# SQL data Insertion slow through ssis

Tags: sql, ssis

I am inserting data in to a Table1 from ssis. The data is loading very slow per min(5-10k records) are inserting i have selected fast load option in destination task that option also not helped me.

In the same server for another table (Table2)  data load is happening very fastly which is having more data and more indexes comparing to the  Table1.

Why Table1 data insertion is slow ?

Please help me.

Comment: Table definitions, indexes, triggers etc?

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for slowing loading packages could be various. Usually, they are related to memory, destination, indices, loggings and etc. Have you tried the equivalent query's performance? If that is better, you can use `Execute SQL Task` instead of `data flow task`.

In your packages, do you have `OLE DB Command` transformation or other fully-blocking transformations like `fuzzy lookup` or `fuzzy grouping`? Because OLE DB Command transformation is on a row-by-row basis and all the fully-blocking transformations will create lots of overhead.

It seems that you are using OLE DB Destination, so you may change the MICS (Maximum Insert Commit Size) and RPB (Row per Batch) accordingly. Because the thing is a large batch will negatively affect memory if you have clustered indexes on the target table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
 i am using oledb source and oledb destination i have kept options mics(1000000) and RPB(100000). in between source and destination i am using  lookup to avoid duplicates. 
 
total 5 indexes(non clustered) are applied on the table i have  disabled indexes and loaded, insertion happened very fastly. if one index is enabled also the data insertion is happening very slow. is there any thing i need to check on indexes